# PHP find words which are not in regex

Tags: php, regex

I have written following regular expression `/^[A-Za-z0-9-_\s]*$/` in PHP which allows numbers, letters, spaces, hyphen and underscore. I want to display those matches which are not valid against the regex i.e "My Name is Blahblah!!!" should give me "!!!" output.

Comment: @jason4: do you need any further help with this question? :-)

Comment: Thanks Andy E, carrot always works for me :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the caret symbol inside the character class to invert the match and remove the start (`^`) and end (`$`) characters:

```
/[^A-Za-z0-9-_\s]+/
```

http://php-regex.blogspot.com/2008/01/how-to-negate-character-class.html

Comment: You want to get rid of those anchors, and change the `*` to `+`.  The OP is trying to pluck matches out of the string, not match the whole thing.

Comment: @Alan: yeah, the start and end anchors are gone.  Thanks for the tip on the `+`, edited.

Answer (score 2):

If you replace all the matches with the empty string then you'll get the non-matching parts back:

```
preg_replace('/[A-Za-z0-9-_\s]+/', '', $string)
```

This will work for any arbitrary regex, but for your specific regex @Andy's solution is simpler.

Notice that I removed the anchors `^` and `$` to make this work.

Comment: You should change the `*` to a `+`.  Otherwise you're going to waste a lot of time replacing nothing with nothing. ;)

Answer (score 0):

`preg_replace("/^[A-Za-z0-9-_\s]*$/","","My Name is Blahblah!!!") // Output: "!!!"`

Or, if you want all the groupings of them

`preg_split("/^[A-Za-z0-9-_\s]*$/","","My Name is Blahblah!!!")`

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the hiphen - at the begining or at the end of the character class or escape it, so your regex would be :

```
/[^-A-Za-z0-9_\s]+/
```

or

```
/[^A-Za-z0-9_\s-]+/
```

or

```
/[^A-Za-z0-9\-_\s]+/
```